# Is there a level of trust where one can edit comments of others?

Tags: support, comments, editing-help

I know I can edit my own comments, but only for 5 minutes. What if I detect a relevant typo later? Is there a trust level that allows for editing comments no matter how old, no matter who wrote it?

If I delete my comment and add a corrected version, it is out of context, so anyone' s referring to my comment is now confusing, since the reference is missing.

What shall I do in such cases?

Comment: There is... but... it's not for those kinds of scenarios. Only moderators and above can edit comments of other users or comments outside of the 5 minute window.

Comment: You can flag the comments referring to your now deleted one as no longer needed.

Comment: Usually... if the comment is significant enough to be edited, it's significant enough to instead be an answer or an edit to the post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there isn't. Only moderators can edit comments once the edit window has passed, and they're not going to do that except in the most extreme circumstances. A comment being wrong isn't one of those cases.

If a comment of yours has a relevant typo, you can delete that comment, and repost the correct version, as you mentioned. If that means the comment is out of context, that's unfortunate, but there's nothing much you can do about it. If your deleted comment makes other comments outdated, or irrelevant, then you should flag those as NLN so that they get deleted as well.

Also, I would note that if your comment depends upon its location relative to *other comments*, then you're having a discussion with other users, and that's not really what comments are for at all. Ideally, comments should be able to stand alone, since they should only be used to ask the post author for clarification. In some rare cases, comments can be used to add some information to an answer that is not worth editing into the answer, or posting as a separate answer.